# How to index a pdf document in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf

I am reading a PDF document in Ubuntu 11.04 using the default "Document Viewer". The document is more than 500 pages and it takes a while to complete a "Find ..." for a particular text. Is there a way to index the PDF documents on the above mentioned platform? I am looking for a functionality inbuilt into the reader itself.

Comment: there's answer over on ask ubuntu , for you.

Comment: I tried Okular and it's really good at search and the annotation is also really good. Just need to find out where the annotations are stored so that I can automatically back them up in DropBox.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing programs for PDFs in Ubuntu:

- [JPdfBookmarks](http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.com/)
- [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/)
- [A Wine Index](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5549)
- [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/)
- [Foxit Reader (run under Wine)](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/)